# Android studio 3.5.1(SDK 29.0.3) causes broken avd root

Tags: android-studio

I upgraded android studio 3.4.7 to 3.5.1, and after the update, it causes Broken AVD Root.
I changed all variables and version and check it not work, and finally found that the final Android SDK(29.0.3) version and Emulator(29.3.0) version is not matching.
Need to downgrade the emulator, but Android Studio does not support downgrade emulator.

Using Android Studio 3.5.1, Android SDK(29.0.3), Emulator(29.3.0), fully installed SDK content.

Comment: Can you try paraphrasing your question in a clearer manner?

Comment: Newer version of Android Studio causes Emulator Panic : Broken AVD Root.
Cannot fixed as update or downgrade SDK, and system variable is not effective solution at this version.

Comment: are you on mac or windows?

Comment: Using windows 10.